Why did Henry VIII execute Margaret de la Pole?
Margaret de la Pole was, arguably, a Yorkist claimant to the English throne, but never appears to have pressed her claim. Her sons were, certainly, troublesome to Henry, particularly after his break with Rome,but I have never understood why Henry felt it necessary to execute Margaret.
She was a woman, a serious disqualification from power in the 16th century. And she was old, 67 at the time of her execution. Unfortunately, she could not be bundled off to a convent, as Henry dissolved them, but she could simply have been kept in prison until she died, which at her age would have been sooner rather than later. Mary Stuart was imprisoned for nearly 40 years before she was executed, arguably with more reason than de la Pole.
Henry VIII executed a number of people who opposed him, but even for him this seems gratuitously vicious.
(Wikipedia is not very helpful, somewhat confused)

In addition to her sons opposing Henry over his decision to break with Rome and divorce Queen Catherine; Margaret Pole was also a daughter of George Plantagenet, Duke of Clarence and as such was the last surviving Plantagenet after the execution of her brother in 1499. This, by itself did not condemn her as she and the descendants of Edward IV through his younger daughters and Arthur Plantagenet, Viscount Lisle ( illegitimate son of Edward IV) were mostly left alone but after the Pilgrimage of Grace which was supported by Reginald Pole and Henry Courtney, Marquess of Exeter ( a grandson of Edward IV through Catherine of York) ; his policy towards the Plantagenets and their descendants hardened and even Lisle was imprisoned for 2 years from 1540-1542 due to the King's paranoia and was released in 1542 only to die soon.
For further information, you may read The Tudors and the Royal Race by M.L Bush.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/24406720?seq=5
